# Block direct access to PHP file except from AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax

I wish to have a webpage that uses AJAX to access a PHP file in `./ajax/file.ajax.php`

Trouble is, I don't want people to be able to type the address in their browser to access that PHP file directly.

Is there a way I can make it so that only AJAX requests can access the file?

Is there something I can check for in the PHP file to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery to make the XHR, it will set a custom header `X-Requested-With`. You can check for that and determine how to serve your response.

```
$isXhr = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"])
         AND strotlower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) == "xmlhttprequest";
```

However, this is trivial to spoof. In the past, I've used this to decide whether to render a whole page (if not set) or a page fragment (if set, to be injected into current page).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `jQuery` or you are not interested/you can't use custom headers (to go with what `alex` has offered), you may just simple `POST` some data with your Ajax request, and in that specific file check if that data has sent or not. If you send by `GET` it would be visible on the address bar, that's why I suggest `POST`.

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['valid_ajax']))
    header('Location: /');

?>
```

It's not solid as you can fool that with providing handmade data, however that's better than nothing if your problem is not that critical.

Comment: This worked great!!! Don't know why no one has up voted this answer until I did..